# Migrate Inspection rules from eclipse to IntelliJ

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

I am an IntelliJ user and really love the inspection it supports. However, from one of my friend, I wish to use the eclipse rules he has created I see an Import option in IntelliJ. Is the import option for the file that is exported from IntelliJ? Or can eclipse also export in a format that IntelliJ can import? Also, can I use/download static analysis rules from a central server in IntelliJ?